# What is the 'head' of a linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I'm working in linked lists in Java, so I'm trying to grasp the concept of a single linked list.

`head -> 12 -> 34 -> 56 -> null`

`head.next` would be 12 (also the same as node1). However, what is head then?

**Update:** What is the difference between a reference and a pointer?

**Update2:** So if `head` is `12` and `head.next` is `34`, then doesn't mean this following function skips the first node to see if it's null?

```
public void add(Object data, int index)
    // post: inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.
    {
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        Node current = head;
        // crawl to the requested index or the last element in the list,
        // whichever comes first
        for(int i = 1; i < index && current.getNext() != null; i++)
        {
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        // set the new node's next-node reference to this node's next-node reference
        temp.setNext(current.getNext());
        // now set this node's next-node reference to the new node
        current.setNext(temp);
        listCount++;// increment the number of elements variable
    }
```

Source: http://www.mycstutorials.com/articles/data_structures/linkedlists

Comment: Now try reading the question out of context. It doesn't make any sense :)

Comment: A little context might help...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The head of the list refers to the first node of the list. It would make a good name for the variable storing the reference of that node, and I would expect it to contain the null-reference if the list was empty

```
someLinkedList.head
         |
         |
         v
        ______        ______        ______            
       |    |n|      |    |n|      |    |n|           
       |    |e|      |    |e|      |    |e|           
       | 12 |x| -->  | 34 |x| -->  | 56 |x| --> null
       |    |t|      |    |t|      |    |t|           
       |____|_|      |____|_|      |____|_|
```

Depending on context, the tail can refer to different things. The terminology I'm used to says that the tail corresponds to `34 -> 56 -> null` in this example, that is, the list that follows the head.

In other contexts, it may be a reference to the last node. In such interpretation, the tail would refer to the `56` node in your example.

---

Regarding your first edit, which happens to be a *completely different question*:

A pointer is a value corresponding to a memory address. A reference is value referring to some object (or null). You can't do pointer arithmetic on Java references, but otherwise I'd say they are fairly similar.

What may confuse you, is that variables in Java can *never contain objects*. Objects always live on the heap, and variables contain primitive data types, or references to objects on the heap.

---

Regarding your second edit:

In the example you provided, it looks like the add method skips the first element, and in a sense it does. This is because the implementation has a "dummy"-element as the head. Look at the initialization of the head-variable in the constructor:

```
head = new Node(null);
```

I can't understand why they've decided to do that. To me it looks plain stupid.

Comment: So, head.next would give 12, and head.next.next would give 34, correct? So what is head (you said null right?)? The tail always points to the node that points to the "null" correct?

Comment: No, `head` would refer to the `12`-node. `head.next` would be `34` (you've followed *one* `next` reference!). Keep in mind that `head` is not an object, it's a reference.

Comment: What about my question about the tail? Also, I am a little confused, I'll update my question.

Comment: (Please don't use this as a discussion-thread. If you have more questions, click the ask-question link.)

Comment: Answer updated. Now please create a new question if you have any follow-up questions.

Comment: Actually most implementations of lists use a dummy node for the head/tail nodes because it makes the code a bit simpler (you don't need to check for null everywhere). The java implementation does this as well.

Comment: @Voo, ah, interesting point. I see that too now. That explains a lot.

Comment: In C++, we always use `* head` to declare the head, and in C++ `*` means pointer (`&` means reference). what's more, **reference** can't be changed, but pointer can be (as *head* can be changed to point another node). So I am confused. Can you explain why you said **head** is a **reference**?

Comment: Because a reference in Java is more similar to a pointer in C++.

Answer (score 13):

The term “head” has two completely unrelated meanings. The most common (that comes out of Lisp, I believe) is “ the first element of the list.” Judging from your diagram, that is not the meaning you have in mind.

The second meaning refers to a technique to deal with the following issue: If you represent a linked list as just the nodes with data, then when the list is empty, all references (and/or pointers, depending on the language) to the list have to be null, because there is nothing to point at. This creates lots of bookkeeping problems for code that uses the list. A *list head* solves this problem. It is a list node that contains no actual data. A reference or pointer to the list is always a pointer to the head node. The first element of the list is always `head.next`. Usually, the existence of the head is hidden in the class that implements a “ linked list with a head.”

Depending on the operations being supported, there can be a similar bookkeeping problem at the end of the list, particularly for doubly linked lists. A *list tail* node simplifies bookkeeping.

These are also called “ sentinel nodes” in the literature (including the [Wikipedia article on linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)).

Answer (score 6):

yes it is just a pointer to the first node

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth undeserved downvote. The term "point" is not used in the C sense. And it sort of answers the vague question (although it might be a useless answer)

Comment: @Bohzo: I believe this answer has no merit (it's just a guess based on zero information, and it uses incorrect terminology); hence the downvote.

Comment: even if the question has not context this question is asking about a linked list, and yes Java does have "pointers" you just don't really have control over them.

Comment: @Tbone: There's a much more appropriate term, and that's "reference"!

Comment: Sorry, you are right, my first language is C++ so when I see a reference I think of a pointer :)

Comment: But in C++, we always use `* newNode` to declare a new node, so how can this be a reference? `*` in C++ is a **Pointer**...

Comment: *"so how can this be a reference?"* -- Because we're not discussing C++ here. We're discussing Java, and in Java a reference is not what you are used to.

Answer (score 5):

Before Anything else It should be noted that head is not a separate node, but just a reference to the first node. It keeps the whole list by storing a pointer to the first node.

*Another noted difference is that head is an ordinary local pointer variable which is stored in stack, whereas list nodes gets stored in heap.*
**So In most jargon terms Head is just a local pointer which keeps reference to the first element of a linked list and is mostly initialised with NULL in order to distinguish an empty linked list.**

Comment: If the first element, say `list1`, if `list1.next != null`, and you set it to be **NULL**. Will you break the first element's link to the next element? I mean will the first element be a single element alone without pointing to other element?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you set `list1.next` to `null`, then the `list1` node will effectively be the last node in the list.

Comment: Yes Indeed..here in that case
list1 == head pointer..
So if I make list1.next=NULL only one node will be left in the list.Moreover   to make whole list empty you have to make list1=NULL.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is simple difference. With `head` pointer `list` creation is managed by the `LinkedList` class itself, however without `head` pointer - the client code requires to keep track of first, and then adding the rest of the `nodes`

However, both with or without `head` pointer - creates functional `LinkedList`

Modern go-to style linkedlist without `Head` pointer(From Leetcode)

```java
public class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode() {}
    ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
    ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
  }
```

To create `LinkedList`

```java
ListNode listNode = new ListNode(4, new ListNode());
listNode.next = new ListNode(1, new ListNode());
listNode.next.next = new ListNode(10);
```

Now with `head` pointer:

```java
public class SingleList {
    Node head;

    static class Node{
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node(int d){data = d;}
    }

    public void insertNode(int n){
        Node new_node = new Node(n);
        if(head == null){
            head = new_node;
        } else{
            Node cur_node = head;
            while(cur_node.next !=null){
                cur_node = cur_node.next;
            }
            cur_node.next = new_node;
        }
    }
}
```

To create `Linkedlist`

```java
SingleList singleList1 = new SingleList(6);
singleList1.insertNode(3);
```

See - linkedlist creation in client program - for above different `Linkedlist` implementation.