# What really is the head of a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable

I have a question regarding linked lists and hash tables in C.

Is the so called head of the linked list supposed to be just a pointer to the first node or can the head be the first node?

```
void insert(int item)
{
    //Making space for a new node
    node *link = malloc(sizeof(node));
    //Checking if valid
    if (link == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    //Assigning the value of the node
    link->value = item;
    //Assigning the next to be the first element
    link->next = first;
    //Assigning first to be the current node
    first = link;
}
```

Above code is from my insertion function of linked list. The "first" is assigned as `node *first = NULL;`
So the question here is that should I make a dedicated pointer that only holds the address of the first node or is this just fine. The code seems to work just fine.

And the same question sort of holds with hash tables. Should the array in hash table hold only the pointer to the first node or should the tables index slot hold the first node.

I hope my question is understandable. Feel free to ask if something doesn't make sense or need more of the linked list implementation I did.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Discussion on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973713/what-is-the-head-of-a-linked-list) and [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/76704/what-precisely-concisely-is-the-head-of-a-singly-linked-list-i-ask-bc-of-ambi). It depends.

Comment: Typically, "head" is used loosely to denote either a pointer to the node or the node itself.  If a rigorous definition is provided it may be either.  Language is imprecise and fluid.

Comment: It is probably best to stick with a term like "head pointer" to refer to a (null when empty) pointer to the first node of the list, although it is also common to name a variable (or parameter) containing a "head pointer" `head`, and it is also common to name a variable (or parameter) containing a pointer to a "head pointer" `head`!